# Docker is changing files ownership and permission, why?

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, docker-container

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: "php71-fpm-nginx"
    build: php-fpm
    ports:
        - 8080:80
        - 9002:9002
    environment:
        PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
        STATUS_PAGE_ALLOWED_IP: '127.0.0.1'
    volumes:
        - ~/dev:/data/www
    links:
        - db
  db:
    container_name: "db_mysql"
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1qazxsw2'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'nortwind'
        MYSQL_USER: 'db_user'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '1qazxsw2'
    volumes:
        - ./dev/northwindSQL:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - ~/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
  elk:
    container_name: "elk"
    image: willdurand/elk
    ports:
        - 81:80
    volumes:
        - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
        - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
    volumes_from:
        - php-fpm
```

Everything is working fine but as soon as I run the command `docker-compose up -d --build` and the containers start up the ownership and permissions in the host at `~/dev` get updated as follows:

```
$ ls -la ~/dev/
total 96
drwxrwxr-x  11     80     80 4096 Dec 15 14:36 .
drwx------. 40 rperez rperez 4096 Dec 15 14:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5     80     80 4096 Mar 13  2015 css
-rw-r--r--   1     80     80  189 Mar 10  2016 DEMO_NOTES.TXT
```

Is this an expected behavior? It's something coming from the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/reypm/another-lamp-docker/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile)? Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, docker doesn't change anything.   One of your apps/processes is.   File permissions on mapped volumes probably don't work the way you think they do -- check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> volumes take the ownership of whatever is already at the path in the
>   container. If the location in the container is owned by root, then the
>   volume will get root. If the location in the container is owned by
>   something else, the volume will get that.